# PIVOTING IN SQL - making col to rows

Tags: sql

I have a table with following data set (INPUT) and I want data as OUTPUT mentioned in the attached picture. I am trying to make required changes with full outer join, as i have numerous hotel keys but this makes the output really really slow.

[image]

With pivot I am unable to do the same as- it requires aggregation of column, which i totally do not need.

Comment: You tagged more than one DBMS, so I removed these tags; please only tag the involved one, because solutions can be far different from one to another.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Arpan, Please use cross join in SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select hotel_key,
       max(case when HotelAddQuestionId = 1 then UserData end) as HAQ_ID_1,
       max(case when HotelAddQuestionId = 2 then UserData end) as HAQ_ID_2,
       max(case when HotelAddQuestionId = 3 then UserData end) as HAQ_ID_3,
       . . .
from t
group by hotel_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for each item in UserData you want to create a new column, grouped by Hotelkey? Are the number of columns variable or constant in Pivoted link you provided..

Comment: Hi 
Yes for each column, I wish to create a new column,grouped by hotel key. And the number of columns are constant, I have list of HotelAddQuestionId for which all the user data has to be taken.